# Test Class Help - Are the correct fields being tested?

Tags: trigger, unit-test, case, contact, update

I feel like I should create a new Contact in the test class so that I can relate it back to the Case. Would this be the right way to go about it?

Basically, to test I want to:

- Create a case and assign the CountryWebFormText__c field an Area value
- Insert the case
- Assert that on Case, the Country_of_Origin__c field == CountryWebFormText__c
- Assert that the Contact.Country__c field == CountryWebFormText__c

To Assert the Contact field, will I have to create a new Contact?

This is my Apex Trigger:

```
trigger WebToCaseCountry on Case (after insert)
{

    Set<Id> contactIds = new Set<Id>();
    for(Case caseObj : Trigger.new)
    {
         contactIds.add(caseObj.ContactId);
    }

    //Update Contacts
    Map<ID, Contact> mapContacts = new Map<ID, Contact>([SELECT Id FROM Contact where Id IN :contactIds]);
    System.debug(mapContacts);
    List<Contact> contactToUpdate = new List<Contact>();
    For(Case caseObj : Trigger.new)
    {
        Contact cont = mapContacts.get(caseObj.ContactId);
        cont.Country__c = caseObj.CountryWebFormText__c;
        contactToUpdate.add(cont);
    }

    update contactToUpdate;

    Map<Id, Contact> mapUpdatedContacts = new Map<Id,Contact>();
    For(Contact cons : contactToUpdate)
    {
        mapUpdatedContacts.put(cons.Id,cons);
    }

    //Update Cases
    List<Case>  caseList = [SELECT Id, CountryWebFormText__c, Newsletter__c, Country_of_Origin__c  FROM Case];
    List<Area__c> areaList = [SELECT Name, Id From Area__c];
    List<Case>  bulkifyList = new List<Case>();
    for(Case caseObj : caseList)
    {
        for(Area__c a : areaList)
        {
            if(caseObj.Newsletter__c == TRUE && caseObj.CountryWebFormText__c != NULL && a.Name.equals(caseObj.CountryWebFormText__c))
            {
                caseObj.Country_of_Origin__c = a.Name;
                bulkifyList.add(caseObj);
            }
        }            
    }

    update bulkifyList;

}
```

This is my Test Class so far:

```
@isTest
public class WebToCaseCountryTest
{
    //Create Cases
    public static testMethod void testCaseGetCreated()
    {
        List<Case> newCases = new List<Case>();

        Case c1 = new Case(CountryWebFormText__c ='CA', Newsletter__c = TRUE);
        Case c2 = new Case(CountryWebFormText__c ='Americas', Newsletter__c = TRUE);

        newCases.add(c1);
        newCases.add(c2);
        insert newCases;
        //Test Country_of_Origin__c field from Cases gets updated to the same value as CountryWebFormText__c
        List<Id> newCaseIds = new List<Id>();
        for (Case caseObj:newCases)
        {
            newCaseIds.add(caseObj.Id);
            System.assert(caseObj.Country_of_Origin__c == caseObj.CountryWebFormText__c);
        }
    }

    //Test Country__c field from Contact gets updated to the same value as CountryWebFormText__c
    public static testMethod void testContactFieldUpdate()
    {
        Case c = new Case(CountryWebFormText__c ='CA', Newsletter__c = TRUE);
        insert c;

        Case caseObj = [select CountryWebFormText__c from Case where CountryWebFormText__c=:c.CountryWebFormText__c];
        System.assert(caseObj.Contact.Country__c == c.CountryWebFormText__c);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Nik. It would be best if you could write your exact problem here. Questions like this("Is this code right?", "Am I doing it right?", "What is wrong with this code?", etc) are likely to be downvoted and eventually closed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you're going to use a Contact in your test class, you should create a test Contact as part of the test.  As you may know, your tests should not rely on the data existing in the system prior to its execution (see [the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_data_access.htm)).

Since you may have to create Contacts for many test classes, it's often helpful to create a test data factory class that makes this easy.  The [Trailhead documents](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/apex_testing/apex_testing_data) include an example of this:

```
@isTest
public class TestDataFactory {
    public static List<Account> createAccountsWithOpps(Integer numAccts, Integer numOppsPerAcct) {
        List<Account> accts = new List<Account>();

        for(Integer i=0;i<numAccts;i++) {
            Account a = new Account(Name='TestAccount' + i);
            accts.add(a);
        }
        insert accts;

        List<Opportunity> opps = new List<Opportunity>();
        for (Integer j=0;j<numAccts;j++) {
            Account acct = accts[j];
            // For each account just inserted, add opportunities
            for (Integer k=0;k<numOppsPerAcct;k++) {
                opps.add(new Opportunity(Name=acct.Name + ' Opportunity ' + k,
                                       StageName='Prospecting',
                                       CloseDate=System.today().addMonths(1),
                                       AccountId=acct.Id));
            }
        }
        // Insert all opportunities for all accounts.
        insert opps;

        return accts;
    }
}
```

The example shows a method that you could use to create and insert hundreds of accounts with a single call.

As a side note, you may benefit from applying the ["one trigger per object"](http://www.sfdc99.com/2015/01/19/the-one-trigger-per-object-design-pattern/) design pattern here.